# How much of the planet's land mass is between the Tropic of Cancer and Tropic of Capricorn

Tags: geology

I know this isn't readily available. I know that it is 68% Northern Hemisphere vs 32% Southern. And I know that it's 68% Eastern vs 32% Western.
My wife asked me why I wanted to know and she got the same answer as always, I am just a curious man.

Comment: "I know this isn't readily available" It's not???  Googled your exact question title, and it gave an answer?  The second answer, from Wikipedia, matches and gives even more details

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question lacks research. Googling the exact title immediate leads to a National Geographic article that specifically says 36% of the Earth's land area lies between the tropics.